# How to use rvest in R to extract a dataframe considering the example HTML page?

Tags: r, rvest

I have this: [html](https://prequest.websiteseguro.com/tests)

Below, a small representation of the available link:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <title>Busca Textual - Currículo Lattes</title>
                                <div class="resultado">
                                    <ol type="1" start="1">
                                        <li><div class="relevancia tooltip" alt="Score: indicador da freqüência relativa dos termos de busca sobre o(s) currículo(s) encontrados."><div class="barra"><div style="width:100%"></div></div><div class="porcentagem" style="font-size:9px; font-weight:normal">100%</div></div><b><a href="javascript:abreDetalhe(&#39;K4247104P1&#39;,&#39;Beatriz_Castro_Dias_Cuyabano&#39;,11678670,)">Beatriz Castro Dias Cuyabano</a></b>&nbsp;<br>Doutorado em Quantitative Genetics and Biostatistics pela Aarhus University, Dinamarca(2014)<br>Pesquisadora do Institut National de la Recherche Agronomique , França<br><br></li>
<li><div class="relevancia tooltip" alt="Score: indicador da freqüência relativa dos termos de busca sobre o(s) currículo(s) encontrados."><div class="barra"><div style="width:99%"></div></div><div class="porcentagem" style="font-size:9px; font-weight:normal">99%</div></div><b><a href="javascript:abreDetalhe(&#39;K4440769J3&#39;,&#39;Fernando_Domingues_Kümmel_Tria&#39;,35889969,)">Fernando Domingues Kümmel Tria</a></b>&nbsp;<br>Doutorado em Evolução molecular pelo Christian-Albrechts-Universität zu Kiel, Alemanha(2018)<br><br></li>
<li><div class="relevancia tooltip" alt="Score: indicador da freqüência relativa dos termos de busca sobre o(s) currículo(s) encontrados."><div class="barra"><div style="width:99%"></div></div><div class="porcentagem" style="font-size:9px; font-weight:normal">99%</div></div><b><a href="javascript:abreDetalhe(&#39;K4437977A8&#39;,&#39;Isadora_Alonso_Correa&#39;,29437672,)">Isadora Alonso Correa</a></b>&nbsp;<br><span class="tooltip coautor" alt="Pesquisador com bolsa de desenvolvimento tecnológico e industrial vigente no CNPq">Bolsista de Desenvolvimento Tecnológico Industrial A</span><br>Doutorado em Ciências (Microbiologia) pela Universidade Federal do Rio de Janeiro, Brasil(2020)<br>Aluno mestrado da Universidade Federal do Rio de Janeiro , Brasil<br><br></li>
<li><div class="relevancia tooltip" alt="Score: indicador da freqüência relativa dos termos de busca sobre o(s) currículo(s) encontrados."><div class="barra"><div style="width:99%"></div></div><div class="porcentagem" style="font-size:9px; font-weight:normal">99%</div></div><b><a href="javascript:abreDetalhe(&#39;K4275806J6&#39;,&#39;Yuri_Tani_Utsunomiya&#39;,19925978,)">Yuri Tani Utsunomiya</a></b>&nbsp;<br>Doutorado em Medicina Veterinária (Reprodução Animal) pela Universidade Estadual Paulista Júlio de Mesquita Filho, FCAV-Jaboticabal, Brasil(2017)<br>Jovem Docente Permanente, FMVA-UNESP da Universidade Estadual Paulista Júlio de Mesquita Filho , Brasil<br><br></li>
</ol></div>
</body></html>
```

Html view:

```
100%
Beatriz Castro Dias Cuyabano 
Doutorado em Quantitative Genetics and Biostatistics pela Aarhus University, Dinamarca(2014)
Pesquisadora do Institut National de la Recherche Agronomique , França

99%
Fernando Domingues Kümmel Tria 
Doutorado em Evolução molecular pelo Christian-Albrechts-Universität zu Kiel, Alemanha(2018)

99%
Isadora Alonso Correa 
Bolsista de Desenvolvimento Tecnológico Industrial A
Doutorado em Ciências (Microbiologia) pela Universidade Federal do Rio de Janeiro, Brasil(2020)
Aluno mestrado da Universidade Federal do Rio de Janeiro , Brasil

99%
Yuri Tani Utsunomiya 
Doutorado em Medicina Veterinária (Reprodução Animal) pela Universidade Estadual Paulista Júlio de Mesquita Filho, FCAV-Jaboticabal, Brasil(2017)
Jovem Docente Permanente, FMVA-UNESP da Universidade Estadual Paulista Júlio de Mesquita Filho , Brasil
```

How to create a dataframe a with the following structure in R:

| # | name | CAPES | graduation | inf1 | country.Grad | year | inf2 | inf3 | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Beatriz Castro Dias Cuyabano | NA | Doutorado em Quantitative Genetics and Biostatistics pela Aarhus University | NA | Dinamarca | 2014 | NA | Pesquisadora do Institut National de la Recherche Agronomique | França |
| 2 | Fernando Domingues Kümmel Tria | NA | Doutorado em Evolução molecular pelo Christian-Albrechts-Universität zu Kiel | NA | Alemanha | 2018 | NA | NA | NA |
| 3 | Isadora Alonso Correa | Bolsista de Desenvolvimento Tecnológico Industrial A | Doutorado em Ciências (Microbiologia) pela Universidade Federal do Rio de Janeiro | NA | Brasil | 2020 | NA | Aluno mestrado da Universidade Federal do Rio de Janeiro | Brasil |
| 4 | Yuri Tani Utsunomiya | NA | Doutorado em Medicina Veterinária (Reprodução Animal) pela Universidade Estadual Paulista Júlio de Mesquita Filho | FCAV-Jaboticabal | Brasil | 2017 | Jovem Docente Permanente | FMVA-UNESP da Universidade Estadual Paulista Júlio de Mesquita Filho | Brasil |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

```
info <- html %>% 
    html_nodes(xpath = '/html/body/div/ol') %>%
    html_elements(.,"li")%>% data.frame()
```

**I'm using this code, but without success. how to make this dataframe correctly?**

Comment: The `name` and `CAPES` fields are pretty easy because they're in different tags (`<a>` and `<span>`, respectively).  The others derive from the text element of the list.  It is easy enough to grab the text element, but splitting it into the relevant columns, when missing values are simply not present will be quite challenging.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong If you can help solve this challenging problem I would appreciate it.

Comment: Can you provide link to the example?

Comment: @NadPat, link add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have included everything except "inf1" and "inf2".

```
page <- read_html("https://prequest.websiteseguro.com/tests/")

data <- tibble(
  number = 1:length(page %>% html_nodes("li a") %>% html_text2()),
  capes = page %>% 
    html_elements("li")  %>%
    map(. %>% 
          html_node("span") %>% 
          html_text2) %>% 
    unlist(),
  name = page %>% html_nodes("li a") %>% html_text2(),
  graduation = 1:length(page %>% html_nodes("li a") %>% html_text2()) %>%
    map( ~ page %>%
           html_element(
             xpath = paste0("/html/body/div[1]/ol/li[",
                            .x, "]/text()[2]")
           ) %>%
           html_text2) %>%
    unlist,
  inf3 = 1:length(page %>% html_nodes("li a") %>% html_text2()) %>%
    map( ~ page %>%
           html_element(
             xpath = paste0("/html/body/div[1]/ol/li[",
                            .x, "]/text()[3]")
           ) %>%
           html_text2) %>%
    unlist
) %>% 
  separate(sep = "(, )(?!.*\\1)", 
           col = graduation, 
           into = c("graduation", "grad_country")) %>% 
  separate(col = grad_country, 
           sep = "\\(", 
           into = c("grad_country", "year")) %>%  
  mutate(year = year %>% parse_number()) %>%  
  separate(col = inf3, 
           sep = "(, )(?!.*\\1)", 
           into = c("inf3", "country"))

Output
    # A tibble: 5,349 x 7
       number name                                      graduation                                                                     grad_country  year inf3  country
        <int> <chr>                                     <chr>                                                                          <chr>        <dbl> <chr> <chr>  
     1      1 Beatriz Castro Dias Cuyabano              Doutorado em Quantitative Genetics and Biostatistics pela Aarhus University    Dinamarca     2014 "Pes~ França 
     2      2 Caroline Mello Pimentel Schuabb           Doutorado em Ciências Naturais pelo Technische Universität Dortmund            Alemanha      2016 "Pro~ Brasil 
     3      3 Eduardo da Cruz Gouveia Pimentel          Doutorado em Zootecnia (Producao Animal) pela Universidade Estadual Paulista ~ Brasil        2007 "Wis~ Aleman~
     4      4 Julio Scliar Rerin                        Doutorado em Medicina pela University of Münster                               Alemanha      2001 "Méd~ Brasil 
     5      5 Márcio Fernando Ribeiro de Resende Júnior Doutorado em Genetics and Genomics pela University of Florida                  Estados Uni~  2014 "Ass~ Estado~
     6      6 Diego Padilha Rubert                      Doutorado em Ciência da Computação pela Universidade Federal de Mato Grosso d~ Brasil        2019 "Pro~ Brasil 
     7      7 Rodrigo Furtado dos Santos                Doutorado em Plant Molecular and Cellular Biology pela University of Florida   Estados Uni~  2020 "Cie~ Brasil 
     8      8 Nádia Maria Vieira Sampaio                Doutorado em Cell and Molecular Biology pela Colorado State University         Estados Uni~  2018 "Pes~ Brasil 
     9      9 Elisa Peripolli                           Doutorado em Genética e Melhoramento Animal pela Universidade Estadual Paulis~ Brasil        2021  NA   NA     
    10     10 Camila Ferreira Azevedo                   Doutorado em Estatística Aplicada e Biometria pela Universidade Federal de Vi~ Brasil        2015 "Mem~ Brasil 
    # ... with 5,339 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

I can get you this far, but you'll need a reliable and robust regex to separate the text that is currently in `text1` and `text2` into the desired columns of the data:

```r
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
html <- read_html("~/Documents/tmp.html")

h <- html %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = '/html/body/div/ol')

name <- h %>% html_elements(.,"li a") %>% 
  html_text()

l <- h %>% 
  html_elements(.,"li") 
capes <- lapply(l, function(x)x %>% 
                     html_elements("span") %>% 
                     html_text())
capes <- sapply(capes, function(x)ifelse(length(x) == 0, "", x))

other <- h %>% html_elements(.,"li") %>% 
  sapply(., function(x)x %>% 
                       html_elements(xpath = "text()") %>% 
                       html_text())

o2 <- sapply(other, function(x)x[2])
o3 <- sapply(other, function(x)ifelse(length(x) == 3, x[3], ""))


out <- data.frame(name = name, 
                 CAPES = capes, 
                 text1 = o2, 
                 text2 = o3)

out
#>                              name
#> 1    Beatriz Castro Dias Cuyabano
#> 2 Fernando Domingues KÃ¼mmel Tria
#> 3           Isadora Alonso Correa
#> 4            Yuri Tani Utsunomiya
#>                                                   CAPES
#> 1                                                      
#> 2                                                      
#> 3 Bolsista de Desenvolvimento TecnolÃ³gico Industrial A
#> 4                                                      
#>                                                                                                                                                   text1
#> 1                                                          Doutorado em Quantitative Genetics and Biostatistics pela Aarhus University, Dinamarca(2014)
#> 2                                                       Doutorado em EvoluÃ§Ã£o molecular pelo Christian-Albrechts-UniversitÃ¤t zu Kiel, Alemanha(2018)
#> 3                                                      Doutorado em CiÃªncias (Microbiologia) pela Universidade Federal do Rio de Janeiro, Brasil(2020)
#> 4 Doutorado em Medicina VeterinÃ¡ria (ReproduÃ§Ã£o Animal) pela Universidade Estadual Paulista JÃºlio de Mesquita Filho, FCAV-Jaboticabal, Brasil(2017)
#>                                                                                                      text2
#> 1                                  Pesquisadora do Institut National de la Recherche Agronomique , FranÃ§a
#> 2                                                                                                         
#> 3                                        Aluno mestrado da Universidade Federal do Rio de Janeiro , Brasil
#> 4 Jovem Docente Permanente, FMVA-UNESP da Universidade Estadual Paulista JÃºlio de Mesquita Filho , Brasil
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>